# Более одного конструктора в классе

Tags: java

Как можно написать два конструктора для одного класса?

Comment: Но вопрос по-моему всё равно останется непонятен

Answer (score 5):

Например так?

```
class Test {
    private int param1 = 0;

    public Test() {

    }

    public Test(int param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{       
    new Test();
    new Test(666);
}
```

Конструкторы можно перегружать по аналогии с обычными методами.

Answer (score 3):

Возможность указать в одном классе несколько конструкторов (или в общем смысле -
 методов с одинаковым названием) называется перегрузкой. Название у всех конструкторов в данном случае одинаковое, а вот типы и количество принимаемых параметров обязательно должны отличаться.

```
public class Constructor{


    public Constructor(){//вариант 1
      //что-то делаем без параметров
    }

    public Constructor(String string){//вариант 2
      //что-то делаем со строкой string
    }

    public Constructor(String string, Integer integer){//вариант 3
      //что-то делаем со строкой string и числовым значением integer
    }

    //и так далее. Главное разные типы и/или количество параметров

}
```

Создаем новый экземпляр класса Constructor

```
Constructor construct = new Constructor();//вариант 1
Constructor construct = new Constructor("Я строка!!!");//вариант 2
Constructor construct = new Constructor("Я строка!!!", 100500);//вариант 3
```

Comment: Примерчик бы ..